# Solve systems of equations graphically on Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

i've searched many webpages and yet can't find a specific and easy answer, so im writting here and hoping to get the answer. How do i solve this equation on Octave graphically?
There is the system:
[system to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rfpV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the solutions are assumed to only be integers this can be a brief way to visually solve the equations by looking at the graphs. Note that the complementary case below the y-axis is don't covered here. Here both graphs are plotted on the same axes using the `hold on` function and is evaluated at integer intervals. Both functions are rearranged to be in terms of `x`. The mouse can then be used to click the intersections points. Hopefully, this serves as a starting point.

[image: Graphing Plot Intersections]

```
clf;
x = (-5: 1: 5);
y = sqrt(29 - x.^2);
plot(x,y,'.-');
hold on

x = (-5: 1: 5);
y = sqrt(9 + 4*x.^2);
plot(x,y,'.-');
```

Comment: @RytisLekstutis No problem, glad it helped!